# Why does Typescript flag a possible undefined value on array length check with greater than but not equals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Given this snippet of a React component:

```
const AccountInformation = (props: { readonly accountData: AccountData | undefined | null }) => {
  const hasMultipleAccounts: boolean = props.accountData?.customerAccounts?.length === 1 ? false : true
...
```

Why does Typescript complain that `props.accountData?.customerAccounts?.length` is possibly undefined when I check if it is greater than 0 `(> 0)` but the error goes away when I check if it is equal to 1 `(=== 1)`?

Is this a case where JS is doing something weird with an undefined property being interpreted as 0?

Writing it this way eliminates the error, but I'm trying to understand the behavior.

```
  const hasMultipleAccounts: boolean = props.accountData?.customerAccounts?.length ?? 0 > 1 ? : true : false
```

Comment: `undefined > 1` is a lot more likely to be an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More simply, you're asking why TypeScript complains about the second of these statements:

```
console.log(undefined === 1);   // false
console.log(undefined > 0);
//          ^−−−− Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)
```

...because any property access operation with optional chaining in it has `undefined` as one of its possible result values.

`===` is more general than `>` is. `===` is used to see if the type of value of the operands match. But `>` is used to either compare two numbers or to compare two strings for relative "greater"-ness. TypeScript also prevents mixing those two:

```
console.log("1" > 0);
//          ^−−− Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.(2365)
console.log(1 > "0"");
//          ^−−− Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string'.(2365)
```

In JavaScript, we're (fairly) used to implicit conversion in these situations, but TypeScript's job is to apply strict typing, and so implicit conversion is generally not allowed. In JavaScript, `undefined > 0` becomes `NaN > 0` which is `false` (as is `undefined <= 0`). But TypeScript sees that as the error it likely is, and flags it up for you.

([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUBXMATWAzAlmLFgAQC8FJAjAJQDcJjA9EybgIbQSwCwAUKEgwESNJhwEipAHwkADPX6CocRClQAiKhpKyFdJeBUj1VXSQ1yNivkA) for all of the above.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `length > 0` you'll need null coalescing:

```js
const i: number | undefined = undefined;

if (i ?? 0 > 0) {
}
```